Which was the first "business jet" equiped with supercritical wing?
Supercritical wings are common in today's large aircrafts. Looks like the Vickers VC10 was the first airliner using this wing but I didn't find anything related to small jets. I've been told that the CL-600 was one of the first business jets mounting such wing, I also heard that the Dassault Falcon 20 holds that honor. Which was really the first "business jet" equiped with a supercritical wing?

The Falcon50 beat the Challenger by two years.
One price of the early SC wing used on the Challenger was terrible stall behaviour. They suffer from a leading edge bubble formation which causes the entire wing to stall from the leading edge. The Challenger and its CRJ descendants have to have stick pushers because of this, because the natural stall flaps up (all flap positions for those without LE slats) must be prevented at all costs.
The Falson 50 avoids this and needs no pusher, but I'm not sure how.
